# Как заменить пробелы в строке на "нет"?

Tags: c, строки

Необходимо заменить каждый третий пробел в строке на слово "нет" используя функции из библиотеки `string.h`. Пытался сделать это так:

```
*strpbrk(str1, ch) = 'нет';
```

Но, как и ожидалось, не сработало. Буду рад если подскажете ещё варианты...

Comment: Раздвинуть строку, освободить место, скопировать туда слово...

Comment: @Harry Ну  вопрос и заключается в том,как это можно сделать..

Comment: Проще всего посимвольно переписывая в новую строку считать пробелы. Вместо каждого 3-го копируете строку `"нет"` (если преп начнет что-то говорить, отвечайте, что вы не мазохист)

Comment: @avp Я так и сделал,мне сказали -  "не пойдет,используй функции из string.h или не приму" Вот я и думаю что же можно сделать...

Comment: Это еще и не плюсы... algorithm есть только в С++ї

Comment: Ну сделайте тот же цикл, только вместо того, чтобы вставлять символы подряд, ищите пробел `strchr`-ом, вставляйте все символы до него, затем `"нет"`, затем снова ищите пробел.

Comment: Или вместо strchr() может быть удобней [strcspn](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn). Вообще, обе для поиска пробела подходят, надо просто написать для себя оба варианта и посмотреть какой из них кодируется покрасивей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написано на скорую руку, так что Вам, скорее всего, придется потестировать ([хотя-бы здесь](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MPfkDn3wdepDyOXN)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *str = "Can you please tell me how to change this ringtone ?",
         *wrd = "No";

    size_t required_inserts = 0;
    char* beg = str, *lst = beg;
    while (beg < strlen(str) + str) {
        if (*beg == ' ')
            ++required_inserts;
        ++beg;
    }
    required_inserts /= 3;

    size_t str_sz = strlen(str)
        + required_inserts * (strlen(wrd) - 1)  // additional space
        + 1;                                    // termination symbol

    char *new_str = (char*)malloc(str_sz * sizeof(*new_str));

    beg = str;
    size_t counter = 0, bytes_written = 0;
    while (1) {
        if ((beg = strpbrk(beg + 1, " ")) == 0)
            break;
        ++counter;
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            memcpy(bytes_written + new_str, lst, beg - lst);
            bytes_written += (beg - lst);
            lst = beg + 1;
            memcpy(bytes_written + new_str, wrd, strlen(wrd));
            bytes_written += strlen(wrd);
        }
    }

    if (lst) {
        memcpy(bytes_written + new_str, lst, str + strlen(str) - lst);
    }

    printf("out: %s\n", new_str);
    free(new_str);
}
```